# How to use boolean attribute to create combined sort key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table called *Message* with the following attributes:

- `message_id`: number (partition key)
- `user_id`: number (sort key)
- `incoming`: boolean
- `subject`: string

I want to create a global secondary index with `user_id` for the partition key, and the combined value of `incoming` and `subject` for the sort key.

Global secondary index:

- `user_id`: partition key
- `incoming#subject`: sort key

Do I have to manually cast the `incoming` attribute to a string (where `true` becomes `"1"`, and `false` becomes `"0"`) before combining it with `subject`? What is the standard way to handle such a scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, I don't think that you can have different attributes like `incoming#subject` only in a global secondary index and separate `incoming` and `subject` attributes only in the original table. The attributes in your index will reflect the ones in the table. The difference between the two representations is that they have a different partition key and sort key. So, you can't "combine" `incoming#subject` just in the index without having this attribute in the table as well.

However, having `incoming#subject` in both the table and the index would solve your problem since its value would be determined outside of the database (when you write into the table). You should thus be able to "cast" it to whatever you want when you insert or update the data--whether it is `true#my_subject_here` or `1#another_subject`.

Let me know if that works for you!